# How can I compare two Java strings without having to worry about case for either one in Parse queries?

Tags: java, android, string, parsing, case

I'm making a program where a user searches for items based on item name or description. I'm using query.whereContains(key, value) since I want it to check if either contains the keyword they're looking for. My question is how can I compare the keyword(the value) to the item name or description but regardless of case. I know Java's equalsignoreCase() exists, but that returns a boolean which doesn't match the whereContains() method's paramters.

Example of what I mean:

If the user searches for "eXAmplE", which will be the keyword, and a description of an item in the cloud is "this is an ExAMplE" exists, the query should include that. How would I go about implementing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by normalizing the case of all Strings involved before comparing them.

something like this:

```
String original = "SoMeCrazyCASE";
String lowerCased = original.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT);
//now work with the lowercased one
```

note - its important to lower case in the root locale to avoid issues with the current language on the machine youre running on

Comment: But I don't think I can normalize the value that already exists in the Parse data browser, can I? If so, would it be like this: query.whereContains("description".toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT), keyword.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT)) ?

Comment: exactly. normalize both your user input and the "database" of strings youre searching in.

Answer (score 2):

```
original.equalsIgnoreCase(other)
```

This is likely to be faster than doing an s.toLowerCase(), extra objects don't need to be created.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
if(myDescription.toLowerCase().contains((keyword.toLowerCase())){
    //do stuff here
}
```

More complex queries may need you to implement the search using patterns.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 String str1 = "hello";
    String str2 = "HELLO";
    if(str1.equalsIgnoreCase(str2)){
        //YOUR LOGIc
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
String str1="HAI";
String str2="hai";
if(str1.equalsIgnoreCase(str2))
{
    //Use your code
}
```